# Bios cannot find Ubuntu 20.04 boot drive on Lenovo with Win 11

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, system-installation, bios, usb-installation

Trying to load Ubuntu for installation, I cannot find my stick drive on BIOS boot list. Only Windows boot manager and two networks.
I apologize for posting a recurrent issue, but I have tried a few suggestions from previous posts with no success. Details:
A Lenovo desktop with Windows 11. msinfo32 tells me that the bios is Lenovo O5EKTICA 07/09/2021 ver, SMBIOS 3.3, UEFI mode. The drive was prepared by using the command `dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-20.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sda1 bs=32M`, and was successfully recognized by other computers' BIOS.
Thanks

Comment: I do not see how that is a boot device. Are you sure you can use dd to make a bootable USB drive?

Comment: This site shows step by step how to use dd and has many more steps and another program that you do not mention using. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-stick-on-a-debian-linux/

Comment: With ```Grub2Win``` you can actually boot from an ```iso-file```. If that is the route you want to go. It would be easier to make a bootable usb-stick with e.g. ```Balena Etcher```, ```Rufus``` or ```Ventoy```. Then boot from usb.